# How to use the LAG function with the OVER Clause properly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag

I am trying to calculate the difference between 2 values within the same column to calculate daily growth, but I am getting this error below.

I have included Over clause in the LAG function, anyone see what I am doing wrong here? thanks

Msg 10753, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
The function 'LAG' must have an OVER clause.

```
USE GrowthRecord

SELECT DBName AS DatabaseName,
       Date AS CollectedDate,
       MONTH(Date) AS Month,
       DAY(Date) AS Day,
       CAST(SUM(CAST([Usedspace(Mb)] AS FLOAT)) / 1024 / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10, 3)) AS [Database Used Space GB],
       LAG([Usedspace(Mb)]) AS previous_day,
       [Usedspace(Mb)] - LAG([Usedspace(Mb)])
            OVER (ORDER BY Day) AS difference_previous_day
FROM GrowthRecord
GROUP BY DBName,
         MONTH(Date),
         Date,
         [Size(Mb)],
         DAY(Date)
ORDER BY DatabaseName,
         Date DESC,
         DAY(Date),
         MONTH(Date)
```

Amended query but still not working.

Comment: You have a `OVER` clause on one of your `LAG`s but not the other.

Comment: Thanks, I literally spotted that after posting :)